# UITableViewCell with dynamically changing the heigh and adding new components?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell which has 50px of height and I would like to change this height to 300px and to append one more view insight the new height. I did a project which you can download and test with all the code and functionality ([Link to the project on DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx9k3xovbj9yt6l/CellBug.zip?dl=0)). The main problem is that when the cell (random cell) is selected the height is changing correctly but the new view (with brown color) is not visible although I can print its frame, type and so on (it's not nil neither hidden). It works well if I select the first cell from the beginning and then all the rest cells work correctly. So it's something with the reusing of the cell but I couldn't find the exact solution. Thank you!

Comment: Can't take a look now, but the whole project is very welcome to work out the problem without guesswork. All iPhone App questions should require this.

Comment: So if I can unserstand it right, you would like to have kind of expandable cells ?

Comment: Radim Halfar, that's right but the expandable part is working. What's not working is that the new view is not visible when the cell takes the new height. The newView is visible only when I start selecting cells from the first one. That's why I think it's something with the reuse of the cells. And here the link to the project can be very useful so you can see the exact problem.

Comment: I tried to explain my problem as clearly as I can so if I missed something please tell me. I really hope someone to spot the problem. Thank you